# jQuery.post() Seemingly being skipped for one reason or another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .post

I am trying to figure out why a call to `jQuery.post()` either isn't fetching the data, or the function after the fetch isn't running altogether.

I have three files included; an HTML file, a JavaScript file, and a PHP file. The HTML contains the modal element I am wanting the eventually bring up with a "delete" button is pressed.

jQuery is seeing the click and running the function for `$.on("click")`.

However, when I try to call `$.post`, according to my chrome developer debugging, it does a bunch of processing and actions with `.post()` but doesn't bring up my alert to tell me that the data I am retrieving from my delete_prep.php is ready to be used to populate the data inside of the confirmation modal.

I am pretty new to using any kind of ajax, and since `.post()` is shown on many of the other stack overflow questions I looked at as the recommended alternative to using `$.ajax()`

I thought that the code listed below would be enough to retrieve the data and then get an alert that says "JSON object" or "associative array" or whatever is applicable. Unfortunately the alert isn't even showing up.

Applicable html snippets

```
<button type="button" data-title="Delete" data-opid="<?php echo $operator['operator_id']; ?>" class="icon-btn delete">Delete</button>

<div class="modal-wrapper" id="delete_operator_modal">
        <section class="modal">
            <div class="modal-bar">
                <button id="close_modal_button" class="close-button">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h2>Delete Operator?</h2>
                <p id="delete_operator_name">Default Message</p>
                <p id="delete_operator_message">If this operator is deleted, their franchises will no longer have an
                    owner, and be marked 'For
                    Sale'.</p>
                <footer class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="closeModal()" id="confirm_delete_button" class="primary button">Delete Operator</button>
                    <button onclick="closeModal()" id="cancel_delete_button" class="secondary button">Cancel</button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

in document script that WILL BE REWRITTEN FOR jQUERY

```
var deleteButton = document.querySelector('.icon-btn.delete');
        var closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-button');
        var cancelButton = document.querySelector('#cancelButton');
        Modal = document.querySelector('.modal-wrapper');

        function openModal() {
            Modal.classList.add('open');
        }

        function closeModal() {
            Modal.classList.remove('open');
        }
```

Script inside the applicable js file

```
jQuery(function () {

    // This will show the delete modal and populate it with the information from the record the last pressed button corresponds to
    function showDeleteModal(id) {

        // This is where the code that doesn't seem to be running begins

        $.post(
            'ajax_php/delete_prep.php', // Gets information for delete confirmation
            {
                id: id                  // Data that is used to run the SQL query
            },
            function (data) {
                var operator = JSON.parse(data);    // Converts to an object so that it can be used as an associative array
                top.alert(typeof(operator));            // DEVELOPMENT checking to make sure it is an object
            }
        )
        ;

        // END NON WORKING CODE

        // Show the modal once the data is changed
        $('#delete_operator_modal').addClass('open');
    }

    $('*[data-opid]').on("click", function () {
        showDeleteModal($(this).attr("data-opid"));
    });

    $('#close_modal_button').on("click", function () {
        // call function to close the modal that corresponds to the button that was clicked
    });
});
```

FINALLY the delete_prep.php

```
<?php
require_once('obsured_path/initialize.php');

$operator = find_operator_by_id($id);
echo json_encode($operator);
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?  Have you tried attaching a `fail()` callback on the post to see if it is being triggered and if so with what arguments?

Comment: I didn't think about adding the fail yet. But I definately will try that right now

Comment: Also as a side note, you mentioned you chose to use post() as a *recommended alternative* to ajax.  post isn't an alternative to ajax, it's a wrapper.  post uses ajax under the hood and simply gives ajax the arguments you give it, and sets the method type to 'POST' for you.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the value of `$operator` that is being encoded?

Comment: It is an associative array from my mySQL query using a PDO statement and being put into that array using `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Alright, that should be fine then.

Comment: Ok so I have a fail being thrown and getting an error of forbidden when I include the arguments

Comment: So that sounds like the request is getting an error code when trying to access your endpoint.  If you open your network console and make the ajax request happen, you should see it return an error code of 403 FORBIDDEN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176678/discussion-between-tyler-lazenby-and-taplar).

Comment: I can't really help you in regards to resolving the 403.  If that is happening there is something with your server setup that is not allowing that, which is outside of my immediate expertise.

Comment: I took care of that server issue, but now I am back to square one - see discussion

Comment: Perhaps change the .post call to .ajax (adding in the required parameters) and see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary from the chat discussion.

There were two issues found.  First, Tyler found that he had a .htaccess file with some rule that was causing the request to return a 403 Forbidden when trying to access it.  He removed that and the 403 was resolved.

Secondly, his script was referencing a variable that was undefined.  After fixing it to point to the $_POST['id'] being provided from the script, it started working as he intended.